# Normalization of a Scheme Example

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

My question refers to an example of the normalisation process of a scheme as introduced at wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_scheme

The statement is that $X'={\displaystyle {\text{Spec}}(\mathbb {C} [x,y]/(x)\times \mathbb {C} [x,y]/(y))}$ is the normalisation of $X := Spec(\mathbb {C} [x,y]/(xy))$. Why?

To show this it suffice to see that locally (here: at each localisation of a prime ideal $\mathcal{p} \subset \mathbb {C} [x,y]/(xy)$ the ring

$$(\mathbb {C} [x,y]/(x)\times \mathbb {C} [x,y]/(y)))_{\mathcal{p}} \cong (\mathbb {C} [x,y]/(x))_{\mathcal{p}} \times (\mathbb {C} [x,y]/(y)))_{\mathcal{p}}$$

is exactly the normalisation of $$(\mathbb {C} [x,y]/(xy))_{\mathcal{p}}$$

therefore $(\mathbb {C} [x,y]/(x)\times \mathbb {C} [x,y]/(y)))_{\mathcal{p}} $  is the integral closure of $(\mathbb {C} [x,y]/(xy))_{\mathcal{p}}$
 the total ring of fractions $Q((\mathbb {C} [x,y]/(xy))_{\mathcal{p}})$.

I don't why does it hold.

Comment: Can you picture geometrically what the situation looks like? Your scheme is the union of the two axis in the plane, they intersect at the origin. The putative normalisation is the disjoint union of two lines (which are labeled in a way such that is easy to understand the normalization map). It should be obvious that the normalisation map is an isomorphism away from the origin (work it out explicetly if you need to). You only have to check what's going on above the origin. So you localize at $(x,y)$ and it should now be fairly straghtfoward.

Comment: Hi. It's indeed obviously clear to me what happens here geometrically, the problem is that I don't see how to calculate explicitely on the level of rings that $(\mathbb {C} [x,y]/(x)\times \mathbb {C} [x,y]/(y)))_{\mathcal{p}}$ is the integral closure of $(\mathbb {C} [x,y]/(xy))_{\mathcal{p}}$. Chine remainder thm isn't applyable here...

Comment: Are you able to show the isomorphism at any point beside the origin?

Comment: And are you ablo to show that $X'$ is normal?

Comment: @A.Rod: To 1: No, I only have the canonical inclusion $\mathbb {C} [x,y]/(xy) \to \mathbb {C} [x,y]/(x)\times \mathbb {C} [x,y]/(y))$ taking into account that it is conserved by localisations. The argument for surjectivity lacks.

Comment: To 2: Obviuosly $C[x,y]/(x)$ and $C[x,y]/(y)$ are normal as rings since their fraction fields are $C(x),C(y)$.  The problem is can I conclude from this to the shape of fraction ring of  $C[x,y]/(x)×C[x,y]/(y))$? Obviously it's localalization
at elements of $(f,g) \in C[x,y]/(x)×C[x,y]/(y))$ with $f,g \neq 0$.
But what shape does it have?

Till now I only know by the canonical inclusion above that it 
contains the fraction ring of $C[x,y]/(yx)$...

Comment: You do realize that $\mathbb C[x] \times\mathbb C[y]$ is not integral. Neither is $\mathbb C[x,y]/(xy)$.

Comment: The scheme $X'$ has local rings which are UFD, therefore it is normal.

Comment: Now take $(x-a,y)$ a closed point different from the origin. Its preimage is the single point of $X'$ given by $(x-a)\times y$. As $x$ is invertible in the localization $(\mathbb C[x,y]/xy)_{(x-a,y)}\simeq \mathbb (C[x,y]/y)_{(x-a,y)}$  the map is simply given by $x\mapsto x$ $y\mapsto x^{-1}y$

Comment: Of course the same story goes for a closed point of the form $(x, y-a)$ (keep in mind that I label points as prime ideals of $\mathbb C[x,y]$, in a more traditional notation the point $(x,y-a)$ is simply the point of coordinates $(0,a)$)

Comment: Now since your scheme is reducible, the normalization is the disjoint union of the normalization of the irreducible components. What is the reduced scheme structure on the irreducible components?

Comment: If you can answer this then you're pretty much done because the reduce scheme structure over an irred comp of $X$ will make the origin look like any other point.